# Store jQuery object into an Array for later use

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I trying to make a script that creates some buttons based on a JSON i pass to it with the attributes I need, like this:

```
var opts = {};
opts.buttons = [{
    type: "button",
    klass: "btn-default",
    text: "No"
    }, {
    type: "button",
    klass: "btn-primary",
    text: "Yes"
}];

var arr = [];
var button = $("<button></button>");
_.each(opts.buttons, function (v, k) {
    button.prop("type", v.type)
        .prop("class", v.klass)
        .html(v.text);
    arr.push(button);
});
```

And then, kind of stringify them, like so:

```
var str = arr.join('');
$('#someEl').html(str);
```

But this is not working as I thought it would. The return is `[object Object] [object Object]` instead of the button tags.

How can I do that? Any help would be very nice.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not adding them to the HTML immediately?  You could simplify the logic a bit, if you can add them on the fly . . .

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery appending an array of elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111740/jquery-appending-an-array-of-elements)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
opts.buttons = [{
    type: "button",
    klass: "btn-default",
    text: "No"
    }, {
    type: "button",
    klass: "btn-primary",
    text: "Yes"
}];

var arr = [];
_.each(opts.buttons, function (v, k) {
    var button = $("<button></button>");
    button.prop("type", v.type)
        .prop("class", v.klass)
        .html(v.text);
    arr.push(button);
});
```

And later...

```
_.each(arr, function (b) {
    $('#someEl').append(b);
});
```

**Note 1**: `opts.buttons` is **not** JSON, it is object literal.

**Note 2**: `$('#someEl').html` sets HTML content, i.e. its argument should be string. You can use:

```
var arr = [];
_.each(opts.buttons, function (v, k) {
    var button = $("<button></button>");
    button.prop("type", v.type)
        .prop("class", v.klass)
        .html(v.text);
    arr.push(button[0].outerHTML);
});

var str = arr.join('');
$('#someEl').html(str);
```

if you insist to use it.

**Note 3**: You get `[object Object]` because the jQuery button elements are casted to string (because of the call of the `join` function), if the `toString` method of given object is not overrided it uses the default `toString` implementation which gives `[object Object]` representation.

Answer (score 1):

```
var buttonsCfg = [{
    type: "button",
    klass: "btn-default",
    text: "No"
    }, {
    type: "button",
    klass: "btn-primary",
    text: "Yes"
}];

//you can use map to efficiently create an array from another
var buttons = buttonsCfg.map(function (cfg) {
    return $('<button>')
        .addClass(cfg.klass)
        .text(cfg.text)
        .prop('type', cfg.type);
});

//you shouldn't work with HTML strings when you already have constructed DOM elements
$('#someEl').append(buttons);
```